# Posts are deleted everyday at night

Tags: plugins, posts, database, customization

So I have a weird issue with WP and that is that all Posts on the site are getting deleted sometime in the night.

Before I turn of all plugins and change theme to default.. I would like to know if anyone knows of any troubleshooting code I can write in order to see what causes a complete deletion of all WP post entries. At least to know if it happens inside the WP or is called somewhere from the outside, like from the DB itself or a 3rd person.

Thanks.

I've looked through the WP-Cron Events (thanks to: s1lv3r)
I've got the following suspicious items:
jetpack_clean_nonces
wp_scheduled_delete
akismet_scheduled_delete

All arguments are set to: []

Answer (score 0):

'Every night' sounds like it's triggered via a cronjob. You may install the [wp-crontrol](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) plugin to see what cronjobs are sheduled in your wordpress install.

If you don't see something obvious there I would also suppose it happens outside of wp. But as you already pointed out, you can only be sure when you revert everything to a stock install (disable plugins & theme).

Comment: I've installed it and I have the following: hourly 3600 (1 hour) Once Hourly, twicedaily 43200 (12 hours) Twice Daily, daily 86400 (1 day) Once Daily, jetpack_weekly 604800 (1 week) Jetpack weekly, doesn't seem suspicious...

Comment: You can edit your question to include the job list. That's better then posting it in a comment. Also you are looking at the available intervals and not at the jobs. Look under `tools` and not under `options` in the menu.

Comment: This looks more or less clean for me. wp_scheduled_delete deletes only posts which are already trashed and akismet_scheduled_delete only deletes comments which are marked as spam.